# Как передать параметры в конструктор класса из метода в этом же классе C#

Tags: c#

Возможно ли вызвать конструктор класса из метода того же класса?
Например, мне надо передать объект типа Textwriter в конструктор.

```
class Class{
Class(TextWriter){}
public void SampleFunction(){
//Отсюда необходимо вызвать конструктор
}
}
```

Comment: ты хочешь создать новый объект или применить какие-то действия к текущему?

Answer (score 2):

Нельзя. Но если нужно такое поведение, можете вынести весь код конструктора в отдельный метод. Но при этом вы потеряете преимущества кода, который может быть выполнен только в конструкторе (например инициализация readonly полей/свойств):

```
class Class
{
    public Class(TextWriter writer)
    {
        Init(writer);
    }

    private void Init(TextWriter writer)
    {
        // код конструктора
    }

    public void SampleFunction()
    {
        Init(new TextWriter());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Class1
{
    private TextWriter _textWriter { get; set; }

    //конструктор с параметрами
    Class1(TextWriter textWriter)
    {
        _textWriter = textWriter;
    }
    //конструктор без параметров
    Class1()
    {

    }

    //вызываем метод с параметрами , вернет  новый класс
    public Class1 SampleFunction(TextWriter textWriter)
    {
       Class1 aClass1 = new Class1(textWriter);
       return aClass1;
    }
    //передаем в метод через параметры в этот класс
    public void SampleFunction2(TextWriter textWriter)
    {
        _textWriter = textWriter;
    }
}
```